# After upgrading the extension to manifest 3 it stopped working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a chrome extension that worked on an old chrome version with manifest v2 and since the upgrade to manifest v3 it stopped working.

The extension uses the 2 following files:

1. closetabs.js

   ```
   runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {  

      console.log("message recived",request ); 
      let curtab;
      let wDomainsArr;
      let wUrl;
      let result = false;

      chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }).then((tabs) => 
      {
        curtab = tabs[0].id;
      });

      chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: false }).then((tabs) => {
        wDomainsArr = request.wDomains;

        for (const tab of tabs) {
          wUrl = tab.url;
          for (const domain of wDomainsArr) {
            result = wUrl.includes(domain);
            if (result) {
              break;
            }
          }
          if (!result) {
            chrome.tabs.remove(tab.id);
          }
        }
      });

      if (request.tab1Open) {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: request.tab1Open });
      }
      if (request.tab2Open) {
        chrome.tabs.create({ url: request.tab2Open });
      }
    });
   ```
2. manifest.json

```
{
"manifest_version":3,
"name":"Close all tabs",
"version":"1.0",
"description":"Close all tabs extension",
"permissions":["tabs"],
"host_permissions":["http://xxxxx:9080/*"],
"background":{"service_worker":"closetabs.js"}
}
```

3. The reason I'm using onMessageExternal is because the extension is being called from a java script in webserver by the following command:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(extensionId, {
      tab1Open: "",
      tab2Open: "http://www.ynet.co.il",
      wDomains: ["walla"]
    }, (response) => {
      console.log("Message sent successfully!");
    }
);
```

I asked chatgpt about the issue and checked all the syntax and permissions.
I also checked in the developed tools and the service worker is running.
The only thing I see is when debugging the java script code in the server I noticed the following error:

```
sErrorMessage = "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined  (reading 'sendMessage') ", sUrl = "", iLine=10
```

And don't know if it's important or how to solve it.

Here is also the code in manifest V2 that works:

manifest.json:

```
{
    "name": "Close all tabs",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Close all tabs extension",
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],
    "background": {
          "scripts": ["closetabs.js"],
          "persistent": false
    },
    "externally_connectable": {
      "matches": ["http://XXXXXX:*/*"]
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
  }
```

closetabs.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse)
  {
    var curtab;
    var wDomainsArr
    var wUrl;
    var result=false;
        
    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
                curtab = tabs[0].id;
    });

    chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: false }, function (tabs) {
        wDomainsArr = request.wDomains;
        
        for (i in tabs)
        {
            wUrl = tabs[i].url;
            for (j in wDomainsArr)
            {
                result = wUrl.includes(wDomainsArr[j]);
                if (result)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (result == false)
            {
                chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[i].id);
            }
        }
    });
    
    if (request.tab1Open != "")
    {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: request.tab1Open});
    }
    if (request.tab2Open != "")
    {
        chrome.tabs.create({url: request.tab2Open});
    }
  });
```

The java script in the server is:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage
(laserExtensionId, 
{tab1Open: "", 
tab2Open: "http://www.ynet.co.il", 
wDomains: ["walla"] }
);
```

Comment: Describe symptoms of the problem. 'It doesn't work' is often not enough.

Comment: The extension is supposed to close all chrome tabs and open 2 new ones based on the url that is being sent from the java script.

Comment: At the beginning of the closetabs.js there is a function call to console.log, but nothing is being written to the console log so I guess that the java script call to the extension doesn't work

Comment: 1) formatted everything
2) I added the manifest V2 code that works
3) I asked chatgpt to take the V2 code and write it in V3. also I asked it for possible solutions to my problem. its main ideas were checking the syntax, the permissions, the chrome policy, debugging with the dev tools.

Comment: @ThomasMueller 1) I'll check the link you sent 2) I wrote the v2 myself from scratch 2 years ago based on different examples I found.

Comment: @ThomasMueller regarding the "externally_connectable" the answer is no. I read that in v3 there is no need for that parameter and that "hosts_permissions" is enough

Comment: @RazGuilleRosman - "regarding the 'externally_connectable' the answer is no. I read that in v3 there is no need for that parameter and that "hosts_permissions" is enough" - Where did you read that?

Comment: @ThomasMueller I asked Chatgpt. I understand from your last answer that it's better not to do that

Comment: @ThomasMueller I read that I do need the externally_connectable parameter because I'm sending the data from a web page. I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: @ThomasMueller Adding the externally_connectable solved the issue. Thanks :)